# how to embed styles?

Tags: python, django

please help sort out.

my problem is that it is impossible to add django1.6 css-file in html-template. my project directory structure is as follows:

```
proj1(catalog)
    manage.py(file)
    proj1(catalog)
        wsgi.py(file)
        urls.py(file)
        settings.py(file)
        __init__.py(file)
        views(catalog)
        templates(catalog)
            index.html(file)
        static(catalog)
            css(catalog)
                styles.css(file)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


import proj1.views.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    url('^$', proj1.views.views.hello),
    url('^datetime$', proj1.views.views.current_datetime),
    url('^dt$', proj1.views.views.current_datetime),
    url('^dt/(\d{0,2})$', proj1.views.views.current_datetime2),
    url('^dynamic$', proj1.views.views.dynamic),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

in settings.py prescribed the following (excerpt):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'proj1/templates/'),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

index.html following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>qwerty</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />           
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <span class='text'>hello,</span> <span class='name'>{{name}}</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

as a result of all this themselves for certain pages appear url (html true), but does not connect css-

ps
windows7

Comment: Use the developer tools (F12) in your browser and look at the network tab. What does it say when it tries to load the CSS?

Comment: ctrl+u/when trying to load style.css - 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your BASE_DIR as the following

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

then use href as

```
href="/static/css/style.css"
```